# React starter kit communication with RESTful backend API service

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-component

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit

I have a backend API server running and I am looking for a frontend framework.  Then I came across this react-starter-kit that seems to be a good candidate.

My understanding is that I am dealing with react components one at a time.  and I can put the all code logic such as API calls, DOM element changes....etc in componentDidMount() so there will be interaction between DOM and the logic. (am I right?)

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import styles from './ContactPage.less'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
import withStyles from '../../decorators/withStyles'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars

@withStyles(styles)
class ContactPage {

  static contextTypes = {
    onSetTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    let title = 'Contact Us';
    this.context.onSetTitle(title);
    return (
      <div className="ContactPage">
        <div className="ContactPage-container">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
          <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default ContactPage;
```

This is the original code of the react component I am trying to hack.  I tried to include "request" module so that I can make http requests.

```
var request = require('request');  // for backend API calls

componentDidMount() {
    request('https://www.google.com')
}
```

It didn't work.  So what I am doing wrong here?  Thanks.

The error message is very long, started with the following message.

ERROR in ./~/request/lib/har.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in /Users/ssmlee04/Desktop/react-starter-kit/node_modules/request/lib
 @ ./~/request/lib/har.js 3:9-22

Comment: what does `request` do? It must be async, so I'm not sure what you're expecting it to do?

Comment: making http GET POST PUT requests.  Even a jquery ajax will do just I don't know how to put those stuff together..

Comment: Okay but you've not specified what the request should do when successful.  You'll need to handle the success event and then pass data from the request to the component's state via `this.setState` for the component to be able to update with whatever data you retrieved.

Comment: ya I will chain .success afterwards when there's no error messages but right now I just see tons of errors..

Comment: I'd suggest reading a few tutorials about using ReactJs with Ajax. You're missing a few key points.

Comment: let me read more about it first. thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Request.js is a lib for Node. It is not meant to be used in the browser. That is why you are seeing the error `module fs not found`. `fs` is the file system module of node js.

Since you are already using ES6 I suggest to use `fetch` (https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) to make request to the remote server. It is already supported by chrome and firefox. To have compatibility with older browser you can use fetch polyfill from github. Here it is the link to the repo https://github.com/github/fetch.

Comment: This is something I don't understand.   Judging from the original code I am importing React from node_modules.  So I guess I can do the same thing using request module?  I used browserify btw..

Comment: yeah you can, but `browserify` doesn't know how to resolve `fs` as this is a module provided by node and it is not in the package.json of request.js. 
Make sense?